# JavaFX - how to set CellFactory for specific TreeItem

Tags: javafx, treeview, javafx-8

I have a TreeView, with many TreeItem. what i want to do is that i enable modification for the selected TreeItem and disable it for others.
To get all the TreeView to be modifiable i use :

```
    syTree.setEditable(true);
    syTree.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeCell.forTreeView());

        }

        syTree.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TreeView.EditEvent<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(TreeView.EditEvent<String> t) {      

syTree.getRoot().getChildren().set(syTree.getRow(t.getTreeItem()), new TreeItem<String>(t.getNewValue()));
                System.out.println("setOnEditCommit");
                //}
            }

        });
        syTree.setOnEditCancel(new EventHandler<TreeView.EditEvent<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TreeView.EditEvent<String> t) {
                    System.out.println("setOnEditCancel");
                }
            });
```

This line just  change all the TreeItems to TextField when trying to modify : 
`syTree.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeCell.forTreeView());`
How to do it for a specific TreeItem ?
Any help please ?

Comment: Are you saying that if you double-click a cell in the tree to try to edit it, all the cells display a `TextField`?? That sounds like there is something drastically wrong with some of the code you are not showing us. Can you create and post a simple [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows this behavior?

Comment: This code is doing as u said exactly ! and it's working! (Double click on an item --> TreeItem to TextFied, clicking enter --> new TreeItem with the modified Value take the old one's place "that's what `setEditCommit` is doing") what i'm still trying to do, is for example activate this feature for only the Children of a specific TreeItem because it's working for all of them now.

Comment: OK, so you are saying you want some cells to be editable and some cells not to be editable, depending on some condition on the `TreeItem` they are displaying. Yes, that's possible...

Comment: Yes! that's what i want, i tried at first setGraph() but it's not really what i wanted. My problem here is that the `setCellFactory` just make all the TreeItems modifiable, am i out of the track ? should i use something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are saying you want some cells to be editable, and some not to be editable, depending on some condition on the `TreeItem` they are displaying. If so, it's possible, you just need to do a little more work with your cell factory:

```
Callback<TreeView<String>, TreeCell<String>> defaultCellFactory = TextFieldTreeCell.forTreeView();

syTree.setCellFactory((TreeView<String> tv) -> {
    TreeCell<String> cell = defaultCellFactory.call(tv);
    cell.treeItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldTreeItem, newTreeItem) -> {
        if (newTreeItem == null) {
            cell.setEditable(false);
        } else if ( /* newTreeItem should be editable */) {
            cell.setEditable(true);
        } else {
            cell.setEditable(false);
        }
    });
    return cell ;
});
```